# Difference in area of polygon and excised raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, layers

I'm using QGIS 3.8. I have dowloaded GLOBCOVER 2009 raster land cover map and ecoregions shapefile. Polygon of ecoregions are used for mask to cut raster file. On new layer `r.report` was performed to measure land cover types.

I have found difference between area of polygon and excised raster layer. For example, Ural montane forest and tundra ecoregion is 175533 km2 and the result of r.report:

[image]

Total area is 116576,1 km2. Difference is 58956,88 km2. What causes the difference?

Comment: In what projection did you do your analysis?

Comment: I used WGS84 projection.

Comment: Then how did you calculate area?

Comment: I used r.report for raster layer and field calculator $area for vector layer.

Comment: The difference should be explained by comparing the documentation for the `$area` function and the `r.report` algorithm. `$area` uses "the current project's ellipsoid setting and area unit settings". It's not obvious how `r.report` does it, but you can probably figure it out if you dig further into the GRASS manual. Here's a link to the `r.report` documentation: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.report.html